# Page does not refresh after clicking on anchor

Tags: javascript, html

### I placed a simple translator with javascript. The page is not loading after clicking while the address is changing

```
    <a href="#fr" data-reload>Francais</a>
    var dataReload = document.querySelectorAll("[data-reload]");
    // Define language reload onclick illiteration
    for (i=0;i <= dataReload.length; i++) {
        dataReload[i].onclick = function() {
            location.reload(true);
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you set the specified URL into location, issue `window.location.reload(true)`. This will force browser to reload the page.